Как вытянуть все данные по связям из таблиц в laravel?
Подскажите, как можно вытянуть все данные из группы связанных таблиц через модель user в ларавел, все по типу многие к одному.
Таблицы следующие:
Country->city->office->user
Подскажите как построить запрос, чтобы через модель User можно получить все данные из всех таблиц и обратиться к этим данным в view?

Что такое «Ошибка XY»?

В модели User прописываете все связи, и в запросе что-то типаUser::with(['office', 'city', 'county'])->get();

Country::with([
    'cities' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'name', 'country_id'); // выберите только нужные столбцы для City
    },
    'cities.offices' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'name', 'city_id'); // только необходимые поля для Office
    },
    'cities.offices.users' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'name', 'office_id'); // только нужные поля для User
    }
])->select('id', 'name') // выберите только нужные поля для Country
->get();

Это более простой запрос, но меньше контроля, может загрузить не нужные поля, и повысит нагрузку. ( всегда контролируйте свои запросы )
 Country::with('cities.offices.users')->get();

